# Clojure installed, but clj fails

Tags: powershell, clojure

I installed Clojure via Powershell on Windows 10 and it installed without any errors.  When I typed "clj" however, it gave me the following error:

```
clj : The 'clj' command was found in the module 'ClojureTools', but the module could not be loaded. For more
information, run 'Import-Module ClojureTools'.
At line:1 char:1
+ clj
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (clj:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

I installed it to the following location: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Follow the instruction in the error message and run `Import-Module ClojureTools` - you should then get a more specific error message.

Comment: I know you asked about Powershell, but if you can install and run clojure under WSL or WSL2 you'll probably have fewer issues.

Comment: I did run `Import-Module ClojureTools`, and I got the following error:                 
`Import-Module : File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ClojureTools\ClojureTools.psm1 cannot be loaded
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module ClojureTools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to do run:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

Because your system does not allow execution of downloaded scripts. Of course decision about how much this is secure for you is completely up to you.
I'd recommend to check this tutorial, written by me:

https://github.com/littleli/scoop-clojure/wiki/Getting-started

It provides alternative, and more convenient way to install Clojure. Also it provides easy path for updates and enables access to a growing amount of utilities that you may find helpful.

Finally. If you have access to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2), I'd probably go in that direction.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!!